# In JavaScript how to fix the initial difference between display of elements and creation of variables

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to measure the time between a box aparition and the time of the user click on the box, so I made this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    background: gray;
  }
  #box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    visibility: "hidden";
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
      var clickedTime; //to store the time when the box is clicked
      var createdTime; //to store the time when the box is created
      var reactionTime; //secs between the box creation and box click

      function appear(){
      //this function is to make the box appear
        setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
          createdTime = Date.now();
          console.log("createdTime: "+createdTime);
        }, Math.random()*5000);
      }
      document.getElementById("box").onclick = function(){
        //this is to hide the box, make it appear and calculate the reaction time
        clickedTime = Date.now();
        console.log("clickedTime: "+clickedTime);
        reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime)/1000;
        console.log("reactionTime: "+reactionTime);
        alert(reactionTime);
        this.style.visibility = "hidden";
        appear();
      }
      appear();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem happens when the user clicks on the box fast at the beginning, at this point an alert with NaN is shown and the console log shows:

- clickedTime: 1428200428320
- reactionTime: NaN

By simple observation at this point there is no content in the createdTime variable, even when the box is set to visible when the function appear() is called and this function also assigns a value to the variable createdTime. Another point is that the box is displayed very fast even when I set a timeout, the box should appear after a random delay.

For the second and consecutive my code works pretty well.
My question is about how to avoid/fix this phenomena?, and I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, change this:

```
visibility: "hidden";
```

… to this:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Otherwise, the element starts out visible, so `createdTime` may not have been initialized on the first click.

**Snippet:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var clickedTime; //to store the time when the box is clicked
  var createdTime; //to store the time when the box is created
  var reactionTime; //secs between the box creation and box click

  function appear() {
    //this function is to make the box appear
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
      createdTime = Date.now();
      console.log("createdTime: " + createdTime);
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
  }
  document.getElementById("box").onclick = function() {
    //this is to hide the box, make it appear and calculate the reaction time
    clickedTime = Date.now();
    console.log("clickedTime: " + clickedTime);
    reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
    console.log("reactionTime: " + reactionTime);
    alert(reactionTime);
    this.style.visibility = "hidden";
    appear();
  }
  appear();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```